# Getting "AttributeError: 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'astype'"

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame([  
    [1,2,3,4,np.NaN],  
    [1,3,5,7,np.NaN],  
    [0,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,8],  
    [5,4,3,2,1],  
    [0,2,4,6,8]])

print(df)  
print(df.fillna(
    df.rolling(window=3,min_periods=1)
    ))
```

I'm trying to fill Null values using rolling and getting AttributeError?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is missing some aggregate function, e.g. `mean`, `sum`, ...:

```
print(df.fillna(df.rolling(window=3,min_periods=1).sum()))
   0    1    2     3    4
0  1  2.0  3.0   4.0  NaN
1  1  3.0  5.0   7.0  NaN
2  0  5.0  8.0  11.0  8.0
3  5  4.0  3.0   2.0  1.0
4  0  2.0  4.0   6.0  8.0
```